# reconstruction loss for disentangled variational autoencoders

Tags: python, accuracy, loss-functions, measurement-error, autoencoders

I am using disentangled variational autoencoders which is a variant of VAE. You will find the github code in [this link](https://github.com/emnajaoua/beta_variational_autoencoders/blob/master/disentangled_vae%20(1).ipynb).

I want to quantify the difference or the loss between the ground truth (test_data) and the regenerated test data.
In the link, I am only visualizing the ground truth and the predicted ones but I want to quentify the difference between them.
So, which measure should I use in this case ?
Just implement the accuracy function ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different reconstruction losses that you could use, but it's not a bad idea to use losses from some previous papers. In INFO VAE, the author Shengjia Zhao uses square loss between input and output as the reconstruction loss.

You might want to look at some of the different reconstruction losses that different authors use, but Square loss is a great start!